# How to achieve Transition animation in Pre lollipop devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-animation

I am using Transition animations for activities in material design devices. Is this possible on devices using pre-"lollipop" android versions? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following libraries which might help you in achieving what you wanted..

[Material-Animations](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations)

[transitions-everywhere](https://github.com/andkulikov/transitions-everywhere)

[PreLollipopTransition](https://github.com/takahirom/PreLollipopTransition)

Comment: How do you use that material animation? it's just an example for lollipop and above.